# Unable to run war file on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: java, angular, spring, amazon-web-services

I am working on a spring boot application with latest Angular 7. I have created a build and generated war file.

I have configured a folder in this the structure is :

```
project-tool.war
config/application-prod.yml
config/application-dev.yml
config/application.yml
run.sh 
run.bat
```

In run.sh/run.bat, these command written -> **java -jar project-tool.war --spring.profiles.active=prod --spring.config.location=config\application-prod.yml**

I have created Oracle database instance on AWS and put the configuration in application-prod.yml.

Then I have run this project using the war file on Windows OS, it works fine.

I have to run this war file on Amazon EC2 instance. So I have uploaded this folder on EC2 medium instance. As I run this, it throws an error :

```
2019-03-02 06:50:53.489 ERROR 3082 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/ec2-user/theProject/project-tool.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/com/myProject/security/DomainUserDetailsService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'auditLogService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auditLogService' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/ec2-user/theProject/project-tool.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/com/myProject/service/AuditLogService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'auditLogRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#44dbafd9' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#44dbafd9': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
2019-03-02 06:50:53.551  WARN 3082 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource$ThreadedCachingBlockSource$BlockReleaser.run(BlockSource.java:327)
2019-03-02 06:50:53.556  WARN 3082 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
```

I also have another instance and other project working (spring and angularJS) fine in a similar manner. But why this not working, is there any issue with the command or with angular?

How to work it on Amazon EC2?

Comment: This is not an issue with Angular

Comment: @Niladri, yes I thought same, but earlier application generated War working fine, but this not running. Spring boot is also latest: 2.0.3

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here reading your error stack trace is the database connection. Pay attention to the core error message:

> Failed to initialize pool: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

I don't know how the Oracle database is configured but probably you have a problem with database listener configuration or more simply whit the network communication between your EC2 and Oracle Database instance i can suggest to try to see on the security group and network configuration.

The problem is not Angular but the database link between your app and the database.